# Error Message Not Displaying

Tags: c#, web

I am trying to have an error message displayed when a username and password are not recognized.

```
if (rdr.Read())
{
    int id = int.Parse(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
    string fname = rdr.GetString(1);

    Session["ID"] = id;
    Session["FName"] = fname;
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
else 
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?err='blabla'"); //Display message
}
```

The following code (Page_Load) is supposed to be invoked in the else statement, but it is not:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string err = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            err = Request.Form["err"];
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this the case?
Thank you all so much!

Comment: I would say it's not being invoked because that's not the page you're redirecting to - but I guess I could be wrong. It seems you're placing the code in `Default.aspx` but it should be in `Login.aspx`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a GET value in the query string, not a POST value in the form. You can use [`Request.QueryString[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) or [`Request[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h55b6cak.aspx) which contains POST and GET values.

```
if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
    err = Request.QueryString["err"];
}
```

or

```
if (Request.Count > 0)
{
    err = Request["err"];
}
```

Also, the query string value belongs to the Login page, so you won't be able to access it from `_Default`. Move your `Page_Load` logic to Login.aspx.cs.

Comment: Though you point out a valid issue - I think the more immediate issue is that the code is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, based off the class name `_Default`, I believe you have placed this code in the `Default.aspx` page. Place the code in the `Load` for the `Login.aspx` page. And then also follow the direction provided by jrummell.